# Split sentence into letters and add dynamic class (position of that letter) to it

Tags: javascript, regex

I 'am trying to split a sentence/word into separate letters and was able to achieve using below code.

```js
var textWrapper = document.getElementById("heading");
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");
```

```html
<h1 class="heading" id="heading">
 Hello!
</h1>
```

**Input**

```
<h1> Hello! </h1>
```

**What I get from this**

```
<h1>
 <span class="letter">H</span>
 <span class="letter">e</span>
 <span class="letter">l</span>
 <span class="letter">l</span>
 <span class="letter">o</span>
 <span class="letter">!</span>
</h1>
```

**What I want**

```
<h1>
  <span class="letter-1">H</span>
  <span class="letter-2">e</span>
  <span class="letter-3">l</span>
  <span class="letter-4">l</span>
  <span class="letter-5">o</span>
  <span class="letter-6">!</span>
</h1>
```

What can I do to achieve this?

```
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter-{what should I do here?}'>$&</span>");
```

If it is not possible this way, I am ok with some other way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use regex for this you can [pass a callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to `replace()` and access the `match` and `offset` of the match within the entire string.

```js
var textWrapper = document.getElementById('heading');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
  /\S/g,
  (match, offset) => `<span class='letter_${offset}'>${match}</span>`
);

console.log(textWrapper.outerHTML);
```

```html
<h1 class="heading" id="heading">
 Hello!
</h1>
```

If you don't want to rely on the `offset` but instead want a controlled counter you can increment your own, here using a closure

```
((c)=>(match) => `<span class='letter_${c++}'>${match}</span>`)(1)
```

```js
var textWrapper = document.getElementById('heading');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
  /\S/g,
  ((c) => (match) => `<span class='letter_${c++}'>${match}</span>`)(1)
);

console.log(textWrapper.outerHTML);
```

```html
<h1 class="heading" id="heading">
 Hello!
</h1>
```

Comment: Most answers works here, but this is near to what I want, and this is what I wanted a single line solution, upvoted and accepted, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I have zero knowledge in regex so heres how i would do it

```
    const heading = document.getElementById("heading");
    const letters = heading.innerText.split("").map((letter, index) => {
      const span = document.createElement("span");
      span.innerText = letter;
      span.classList.add("letter-" + (index + 1));
      return span;
    });
    heading.innerHTML = "";
    letters.forEach((span) => heading.appendChild(span));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some kind of loop to add the character index also

```js
var textWrapper = document.getElementById( "heading" );
// `<span class='letter-${++index}'>$&</span>`
const text = textWrapper.textContent.trim();
textWrapper.innerHTML = "";

text.split("").forEach((char, i) => {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.classList.add(`letter-${i + 1}`);
  span.textContent = char;
  textWrapper.appendChild(span);
})
```

```html
  <h1 class="heading" id="heading">
    Hello!
  </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test this code :

```
var content = document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML;
content = content.toString();
content = content.split();
document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = '';
var cpt = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
   const element = content[i];
    document.getElementById('heading').appendChild("<span class='letter-"+cpt+"'>"+element +"</span>"); 
cpt++;     
}
```

Comment: This appends the span as `string`, creating element then `appendChild` will surely work here, but thanks for the answer :)